# multitouch detection is very slow under android

Tags: android, performance, multi-touch

I've a rendered scene that take up to 14 ms to be drawn and displayed.
so the application run without any problem in 60 fps.

but when I start to move my fingers on the device I see that the time increase al lot.
It could take up to 4 ms.

Of course in this case my scene is not displayed in 60 fsp anymore.
is it normal ? May be there is a faster way to detect multitouch ?

my multouch method is this one:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int nbPts = ev.getPointerCount();
    if (nbPts > _nb_touch_detect) nbPts = _nb_touch_detect;

    int pointerIndex = ((ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
    int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
    int action = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
    int pointCnt = ev.getPointerCount();

    if (pointCnt <= nbPts)
    {
        if (pointerIndex <= nbPts - 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pointCnt; i++)
            {
                int id = ev.getPointerId(i);
                x_touch[id] = (int)ev.getX(i);
                y_touch[id] = (int)ev.getY(i);
            }

            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    isTouch[pointerId] = true;
                break;
                default:
                    isTouch[pointerId] = false;
            }
         }   
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Which device? Some devices such as the Nexus One have major hardware limits and this is " normal".